# Python scrapy middleware not working as expected

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I've created a custom middleware class to handle to handle refused http requests.
The middleware is attached to a specific spider and the logs show its attached successfully and detached the original one:

[image]

[image]

Debugging this, I can see that the breakpoint on the `process_response` function in the original retry middleware is stopped while in my custom one it does not stop.

Any ideas?

EDIT:
to reproduce:

spider:

```
import time

import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess


class UsptoPatentHistorySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'quotes'
    handle_httpstatus_list = [401, 429]
    start_urls = [
        'https://patentcenter.uspto.gov/retrieval/public/v1/applications/sdwp/external/metadata/7850271',
    ]
    custom_settings = {'RETRY_HTTP_CODES': [429, 401],
                       'SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES': {
                           'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware': None,
                           'chalicelib.scrapy_my.scrapy_my.middlewares.TooManyRequestsRetryMiddleware': 543,
                       }}

    def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
        yield {"response": response.body}

    def _handle_429(self, response):
        time.sleep(60)
        return response.follow()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    process = CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(UsptoPatentHistorySpider)
    process.start()
```

middlewares.py:

```
from scrapy import signals

# useful for handling different item types with a single interface
from itemadapter import is_item, ItemAdapter
from scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry import RetryMiddleware
from scrapy.utils.response import response_status_message

import time

class TooManyRequestsRetryMiddleware(RetryMiddleware):

    def __init__(self, crawler):
        super(TooManyRequestsRetryMiddleware, self).__init__(crawler.settings)
        self.crawler = crawler

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        return cls(crawler)

    def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
        if request.meta.get('dont_retry', False):
            return response
        elif response.status == 429:
            self.crawler.engine.pause()
            time.sleep(5)
            self.crawler.engine.unpause()
            reason = response_status_message(response.status)
            return self._retry(request, reason, spider) or response
        elif response.status in self.retry_http_codes:
            reason = response_status_message(response.status)
            return self._retry(request, reason, spider) or response
        return response
```

the function "process_response" in the custom middleware is never called

Comment: what do you expect without code ?

Comment: `bug` means problem in code but I don't see minimal working code which we could run and test to find this bug in code.

Comment: you can see that a middleware that was set to none and does not appear in the middleware list is sending debugging message - that is a bug regardless if you have a reproduce-able piece of code.

Comment: try to run  `python your_image` and you will see that it will not run it - so your information are useless. And normally I don't trust what programs display - I had to run it to see it and to try some changes in code to see if it can help or not.

Comment: And even if it is bug,  it still needs to dig in code to find solution - but it is impossible without reproduce-able piece of code

Answer (score 1):

`scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware` is downloader middleware (not spider middleware, see scrapy [Architecture overview](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/2.4/topics/architecture.html) for details)

You didn't disabled original `scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware` 
and you attached `TooManyRequestsRetryMiddleware` into spider middleware (you need to modify `DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES` setting:

```py
    custom_settings = {'RETRY_HTTP_CODES': [429, 401],
                       'DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES': { # not SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES
                           'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware': None,
                           'chalicelib.scrapy_my.scrapy_my.middlewares.TooManyRequestsRetryMiddleware': 543,
                       }}
```